# Why can't I connect to my local SQL Server Express (2014)?

Tags: networking, sql-server, sql, sql-server-express

After I installed Microsoft SQL Server Express (2014) on my local computer (for testing while building a web interface which uses databases), I could connect just fine, but for some random reason, now (after I've finally gotten the .mdb files converted into the .accdb file format I need for use with the SQL Server Migration Assistant tool), I just can't connect/log in.

I am unable to connect whether it's via the Migration Assistant or simply via the SQL Server regular interface.

I am logging in with Windows authentication and the Server name appears completely correct.

I've tried going into "services" on my machine and starting the 'sqlbrowser' service, as that was mentioned as a possible cause for connection failure, but that didn't help.

Also, after reading sites at the following links, I'm still left wondering what this issue could be:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0628296e-939a-4700-b498-1c3c9ce90597/a-networkrelated-or-instancespecific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqlsecurity
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5fc88f64-680f-4479-898f-05099fb19796/sql-server-connection-issue?forum=sqlexpress

Other links I've checked seem unrelated to my situation.

The screen shot below is an image of what I'm seeing when I try to log on:

[image]

Comment: Do you have SQL connection manager (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zxue/2010/04/28/fix-sql-server-express-user-instance-connection-error-in-visual-studio-projects/)? Have you checked this protocol is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

An uninstall and a reinstall of SQL Server Express fixed my issue. Not sure what happened, especially since the original install was only a few days old.